# How to add grails constraints using custom validator when some values from one field act as contraints?

Tags: grails, groovy, constraints

For instance,

```
class Report {

    /* fields */
    String product
    String item


    static constraints = {
       product(nullable:true, inList:list)
       item(nullable:true)
    }
    static List list =['y', 'n', 'tbd']
}
```

So I was trying to implement a constraint using grails constraint such that if a value for the product is 'y' variable 'item' cannot be null or an empty String.

Comment: I believe you can use a `validator` constraint to perform this sort of logic https://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Constraints/validator.html

Answer (score 0):

The `validator` is the way to go:

```
class Report {

    enum ProductType { y, n, tbd }

    /* fields */
    ProductType product
    String item

    static constraints = {
       product nullable:true
       item validator:{ item, report -> report.product != ProductType.y || item }
    }
}
```

Also note the use of `enum`.

Comment: Thanks. How do I do by using a custom validator such as creating a class for validator `class ReportValidator extents AbstractConstraint{ }`?

Comment: validator here is essentially a `Closure` taking 1 or 2 arguments. So, you can extend it

Comment: I think this is going to fail validation if `product` is equal to `y` and `item` is an empty `String` (as distinct from being `null`).  Is the intent to fail `item` validation if `item` is an empty `String`?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown the answers on SO are supposed to give the hints and show directions to achieve the goals, rather than do the whole job

Comment: @injecteer I wasn't criticizing the answer, really.  I was asking the OP of the intent as that will affect the best answer.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Right! The intention here is to fail item validation if the item is an empty String.

Comment: "The intention here is to fail item validation if the item is an empty String." - Perfect!

Comment: I updated the question with that.  Thanks!

Comment: so, no validator update in my answer is needed